# vbnet perform like query with variable

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Definitely I am sure it is sth very easy but I am stuck for some reason.
I have the following which selects the names from database if they begin with the variable s.
But I do not get the result.

```
Public Sub load_oraria_EPAFES_FORM2(ByVal DATAGRID As DataGridView, ByVal LETTER As Button)

    Dim sda As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dbdataset As New DataTable
    Dim bsource As New BindingSource

    conn()
    Try
        MessageBox.Show(LETTER.Text)
        mysqlconn.Open()

        dbdataset.Clear()

        Dim query As String
        query = "select  *  from  db.epafes WHERE (SURNAME LIKE '%" & LETTER.Text & "%  ')    "

        command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)
        sda.SelectCommand = command
        sda.Fill(dbdataset)
        bsource.DataSource = dbdataset
        DATAGRID.DataSource = bsource
        sda.Update(dbdataset)

        mysqlconn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        mysqlconn.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as just as imagined...time to stop,i am probaly tired....
Solution : query = "select  *  from db.epafes WHERE  SURNAME     like '%" & LETTER.Text & "%' "

I was missing some " !